# Access to tabbar Controller from AppDelegate

Tags: uitabbar, appdelegate, badge

I have this situation:
[image]

How can I access the 3rd Tab bar badge from `AppDelegate`?

I've used this code:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    if ([nonLette isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        for (vc in tabBarController.viewControllers) {
            if (vc.tabBarItem.tag == 999) {
                vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
            }
        }
```

but the `self.window.rootViewController` returns "start View" and so does not work.

Answer (score 3):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let tabController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController

            let tabArray = tabController.tabBar.items as NSArray!
            let alertTabItem = tabArray?.object(at: 3) as! UITabBarItem

            alertTabItem.badgeValue = "10"
```

Comment: Looked for this answer everywhere! great work :), I can confirm this works for getting access from the storyboard just fine.  Just remember in interface builder to set the identifier so it works.  Confirming this works in Swift 5

Comment: I did something like this though: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as? UITabBarController,
            let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers else {
            return true
        }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm resolved, but in part!!!

This method works well. With debug, I can see that now I can change the badge on desired tab, but in reality don't change in graphics (the red number not appear).

Some  suggestion?

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *myTabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
    if ([nonLette isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        for (UIViewController *vc in myTabBarController.viewControllers) {
            if (vc.tabBarItem.tag == 999) {
                vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil;
            }
        }
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    } else {
        for (UIViewController *vc in myTabBarController.viewControllers) {
            if (vc.tabBarItem.tag == 999) {
                vc.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nonLette;
            }
        }
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=[result integerValue];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new XCode 11 and Swift 5 this is no longer possible.

Instead you want to do this in SceneDelegate.swift, in particular this function  `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {`

You then want to do something like this.

```
self.window = self.window ?? UIWindow()//@JA- If this scene's self.window is nil then set a new UIWindow object to it.

        //@Grab the storyboard and ensure that the tab bar controller is reinstantiated with the details below.
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController

self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController //Set the rootViewController to our modified version with the StateController instances
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        print("Finished scene setting code")
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
```

Hope this helps for the people using the newer XCode out there.  The key here is appDelegate no longer has access to window, the **sceneDelegate** does.  **If you try to use appDelegate you will get an error that window no longer exists**.

Make sure the **identifier** is set for the tabBarController in the storyboard so it can find it.  You can name it whatever, but just refer to that name in the code here for the `withIdentifier` function